# Gradle doesn't download correct version

Tags: gradle, mule

I want to download dependencies compile 'mule-devkit-annotations-3.3.2.jar'.
But instead of downloading 3.3.2, it download version 3.4.2.

Here is my build.gradle file

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'application'
//apply plugin: 'mule'

//the naming of this artifact
group = 'com.my.project'
version = '0.9.0'
description = "Description here"

//dependencies versions
ext {
    muleVersion = '3.6.2'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7


//application properties
mainClassName = 'org.mule.MuleServer'

repositories {
     mavenLocal()     
     maven { url "https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/" }
}

configurations {
    compile
}

dependencies {

    compile group: 'ca.uhn.hapi', name: 'hapi-base', version:'2.2'
    compile group: 'ca.uhn.hapi', name: 'hapi-structures-v231', version:'2.2'
    compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version:'18.0'
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version:'1.1.1'   
    compile group: 'com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules', name: 'mule-module-data-mapper', version:muleVersion
    compile group: 'com.sun.codemodel', name: 'codemodel', version:'2.2'
    compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version:'1.5.2'
    compile group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb1-impl', version:'2.0'
    compile(group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-xjc', version:'2.2.7') {
        exclude(module: 'jaxb-core')
        exclude(module: 'jaxb-impl')
    }
    compile group: 'commons-beanutils', name: 'commons-beanutils', version:'1.8.0'
    compile group: 'javax.activation', name: 'activation', version:'1.1.1'
    compile group: 'javax.xml', name: 'jax-qname', version:'1.1'
    compile group: 'javax.xml', name: 'namespace', version:'1.0.1'
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version:'2.2.2'
    compile group: 'javax.xml.parsers', name: 'jaxp-api', version:'1.4.5'
    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version:'2.6'
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'4.9'
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'apache-log4j-extras', version:'1.2.17'
    compile group: 'mockobjects', name: 'mockobjects-core', version:'0.09'
    compile group: 'net.sf.json-lib', name: 'json-lib', version:'2.4', classifier:'jdk15'
    compile group: 'opensymphony', name: 'oscore', version:'2.2.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.ftpserver', name: 'ftplet-api', version:'1.0.6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.ftpserver', name: 'ftpserver-core', version:'1.0.6'
    compile group: 'org.apache.geronimo.specs', name: 'geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec', version:'1.7.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.mina', name: 'mina-core', version:'2.0.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.sshd', name: 'sshd-core', version:'0.6.0'
    compile group: 'org.bitbucket.dollar', name: 'dollar', version:'1.0-beta3'
    compile group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcpkix-jdk15on', version:'1.52'
    compile group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk15on', version:'1.52'
    compile group: 'org.fusesource.jansi', name: 'jansi', version:'1.8'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.extras', name: 'bean-validator', version:'4.0.0.Alpha3'
    compile group: 'org.kitchen-eel', name: 'json-schema-validator', version:'1.3.0'
    compile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version:'1.9.5'
    compile group: 'org.mule', name: 'mule-core', version:muleVersion
    compile group: 'org.mule.modules', name: 'marketo-connector', version:'1.2.5'
    compile group: 'org.mule.modules', name: 'mule-module-apikit', version:'1.3'
    compile group: 'org.mule.modules', name: 'mule-module-apple-push', version:'4.0.0'
    compile group: 'org.mule.modules', name: 'mule-module-devkit-support', version:muleVersion
    compile group: 'org.mule.modules', name: 'mule-module-ms-dynamics-crm-ondemand', version:'1.8.3'
    compile group: 'org.mule.modules', name: 'mule-module-ms-dynamics-crm-onpremise', version:'1.8.3'
    compile group: 'org.mule.modules', name: 'mule-module-s3', version:'2.8.3'
    compile group: 'org.mule.modules', name: 'mule-module-twilio', version:'1.4'
    compile 'org.mule.tools.devkit:mule-devkit-annotations:3.3.2'

    testCompile group: 'org.mule.tests', name: 'mule-tests-functional', version:muleVersion
    testCompile group: 'com.cloveretl', name: 'cloveretl-engine', version:muleVersion
}

distTar.enabled = false


task buildZip (type: Zip){
    def muleconfig='local'
    def muleenv='local'
    def filename = 'twilio' + '-'+ version

    if(project.hasProperty('mule_config') ){
       muleconfig = mule_config

    }

    if(project.hasProperty('mule_env') ){
       muleenv = mule_env

    }

    doFirst{
        println "Copying lib"
        copy {
            from configurations.compile
            into 'build/resources/lib'
        }
        println "Copying src/main/app"
        copy {
            from 'src/main/app'
            into 'build/resources/classes'
            filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [muleconfig: muleconfig, muleenv: muleenv])
        }
        copy {
            from 'src/main/app'
            into 'build/resources/'
            filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [muleconfig: muleconfig, muleenv: muleenv])
        }

        println "Copying src/main/api"
        copy {
            from 'src/main/api'
            into 'build/resources/classes'
        }

        println "Copying build/resources/main"
        copy {
            from 'build/resources/main'
            into 'build/resources/classes'
        }

        println "Copying deployement script"
        copy {
            from 'src/deployment-script'
            into 'build/deployment-script'
            filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [filename: filename])
        }   

    }
    doLast{
        println "Copying zip file to deployment-script"
        copy {
            from 'build/distributions/'
            include '*.zip'
            into 'build/deployment-script'
            rename ('build/distributions/*.zip',
            'build/distributions/${filename}')
        }
    }

    println "Building zip file" 
    from 'build/resources/'
    exclude 'build/resource/main'
}
```

The mule-module-twilio-1.4.jar is correctly downloaded based on the version stated above.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure none of your other dependencies depends on version 3.4.2. It seems to me, that some of them need version 3.4.2 and Gradle resolves it by getting the newer version of the plugin.

Comment: I found that after commenting :
compile group: 'org.mule.modules', name: 'mule-module-apikit', version:'1.3'

the gradle will download mule-devkit-annotations-3.3.2.jar correctly. 
But I need both mule-devkit-3.3.2 and mule-module-apikit-1.3

Comment: You can try to exclude version 3.4.2 from `mule-module-apikit`, but there is no guaratee, that  `mule-module-apikit` will work properly with the older dependency

Comment: Yes, it works. I guess it will work properly because previously when I was using maven, it worked properly.
Thank @Stanislav

Answer (score 0):

You can force dependency version with gradle, but be aware that code which transitively depends on newer version may break

```
 configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy {
    force 'org.mule.tools.devkit:mule-devkit-annotations:3.3.2'
  }
}
```